Add egdes parallel
I want to add 2 parallel edges besides of each existing edge, except start and end.
please, can someone help me to create a geometry node setup for this. not like the Fillet curve.



There are many ways to achieve this. Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/, to know what is inside the group node ?

nothing especial in file. this group node ( Curve-To-Mesh Even-Thickness ) is just use for even thickness along the curve.

May I insist because it could be easier to built such divisions during the extrusion process, instead of splitting the mesh afterwards ?

Could we assume that the Input geometry is flat (2D, not 3D) and that all junctions are at 90° ?

add the blender file. please check. I'll hope you can help me out. thanks
not always @90 degree angle, could be any angle. yes later it will extruded to become a 3d object.
